# wordpress .htaccess with permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a permalink working but as soon as I create a post it tells me that soory post not found permalink setting is to "/%pagename%/" and here is .htaccess:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /ryan/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . ryan/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Is your blog in the /ryan/ folder installed? If not, than change RewriteBase /ryan/ to / (or /yourfolder/) and activate mod_rewrite

Comment: yes on our testserver it's under ryan I must have deleted the ryan by accident and  mod rewrite is activated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try clearing the permalink setting in wp_options in the database and then reset permalinks in Wordpress. It's usually `option_id` 30 and called `permalink_structure`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your apache configuration and verify that for the directory in which you store your Wordpress installation you have following settings enabled (probably you will have more configuration options for the specific directory, but these are the minimum required for Wordpress fancy permalinks):

```
<Directory var/www/>
FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have mod_rewrite installed on the server?

Comment: Yes I do have the only problem is that it doesn't find the post when the peramlinks is ON it always says "Sorry no post found"

Answer (score 0):

Try `%postname%` in permalink setting rather than `/%pagename%/`