# Permalinks in Wordpress - Page not found

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks, file-not-found

I've been searching for hours but haven't found anything that seems to be able to solves this issue.

Here's the scenario:

I'm making a wp theme based on the "Twenty Eleven" theme. Everything went fine til I decided to change the urls to permalinks. The only page being displayed is the static page that I have defined earlier.

I have set up the htacces file. In fact, WP did it automatically. Everything works if I switch back to the default setting, but, for SEO, I would rather use the permalinks option.

Here is my htaccess file (it is on my WP installation folder):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mysite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have seen this post [wordpress .htaccess with permalinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157279/wordpress-htaccess-with-permalinks) but nothing there could help me. Any help would be very nice.

**UPDATE :** Things I have tried already:

- Delete pages and create again.
- Access the permalink field on wp_options (db) and setting the value to blank and set the permalink option in the admin again.
- I´m running it on windows 7 through an apache2 installation of Zend Server.
- I thought it was a problem related to my localhost environment, so I put the site online. No luck at all. I'm assuming that wordpress can´t change permalinks to a more friendly url type when you set a static front page. What a shame.

Comment: Unless `mysite` is the folder your site is in, you should remove it, i.e. `RewriteBase /` and `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`.

Comment: Yes, it is =) That was added automatically by the wordpress instalator.

Comment: Do you access your site via `http://www.example.com/` or `http://www.example.com/mysite/` though?

Comment: Well, I'm hosting it on my machine, the url is "http://localhost/mysite".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For those using apache. You will need to

1. Ensure you have .htaccess in root path of  the site you are hosting. Example /var/www
2. Update the  /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

**From**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

**To**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: Lovely. It took me 2 days to solve until I found this.

Answer (score 6):

If editing apache2's default configuration and Wordpress' `.htaccess` files don't help the reason could simply be that apache2's `rewrite` module is not enabled. This is usually the case for those who install apache2 themselves. Wordpress needs apache2's `rewrite` module enabled to support permalink edits. If, like me, you'd rather not edit conf files by hand, apache2's `rewrite` module can be enabled by running these commands as root (I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, so these commands might be different in distros that aren't based on Ubuntu or Debian):

```
    a2enmod rewrite
```

and restart the apache2 service by running:

```
    systemctl restart apache2
```

or

```
    service apache2 restart
```

If you're running Ubuntu 18.04, you can check out all available apache2 modules under `/etc/apache2/mods-available` and see what modules are enabled by listing the files under `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`.

Comment: This solution helped me solve this issue. Also as a note I was running httpd in my server so I had to enable the rewrite module using this guide: https://www.e2enetworks.com/help/knowledge-base/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-on-apache-on-centos/

Comment: @davefogo I'm happy to hear this solution helped. Way to go providing a link to help others learn how to do the same in CentOs. Distros that have little in common usually implement some things differently.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you have found the solution to it, but I solved this problem by simply turning on LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so in httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 4):

Also see [Permalinks on WordPress (Amazon EC2)](http://guiem.info/permalinks-on-wordpress-amazon-ec2/#comment-777)

I had the same problem, but the author in the above link suggested to do three things (it worked for me!):

Go to `/etc/httpd/conf` and edit `httpd.conf`

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Change also AllowOverride if it is set to None

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride All
```

I you haven’t created it yet, place in the root directory of your wordpress
installation a .htaccess file with the following contents:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two 'Directory' sections in the httpd.conf file. 
One is for root folder and another for htdocs folder. 
You must edit both fields to make WordPress pages work again.
Hope it helps.

Comment: This rather should have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me like @Skillachie wrote BUT be also sure to include those settings in the 000-default-SSL.conf file if you use SSL!

```
<Directory /var/www/PATH>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```