# Wordpress installed in localhost does not work for me at all

Tags: wordpress

I couldn't find an answer anywhere and I don't really know how to put my questions too, so I gotta write it here.

Yesterday I downloaded wordpress from wordpress.org and unzipped the package. I out the whole folder named wordpress in my localhost folder (I am using windows). I ran install.php and set up database and it works just fine. But basically I cannot create anything visual. When I go to wp-admin/index.php, it shows me the dashboard, and i would click on Customize Your Site. And I would see my screen like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNFm8.png

As you can see there's nothing on the right side.

Then when i try to change something and save and then click on visit site, it takes me to this page https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFz4t.png

I am really new at wordpress so I dont know what's going on. Could someone please tell me what's happening ?

Thanks!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410921/permalinks-in-wordpress-page-not-found <— Is this any help?

Answer (score 1):

> ...the whole folder named wordpress in my localhost folder (I am
>   usng windows).

I think you might be missing an Apache Emulator. You mentioned that you have a **localhost** folder and your running windows. However, you need a www folder. If you want to do this locally it can be accomplished using a program called **WAMP** which stands for (Windows Apache MySql Php).

Php is a server side scripting language that runs on Apache so putting it in a Windows folder called **localhost** won't execute the php that WordPress. In addition you need to have a MySql database to hold the information... WAMP is easy to install and both MySql and Php are installed in the stack.