# Permalinks in Wordpress - 404 Page not found - Raspberry Pi server

Tags: wordpress, server, raspberry-pi, http-status-code-404

I know that this question has been asked a lot, but I have already tried many things, and none of them work. I get a ***404 Page not found*** error when I visit pages with a permalink other than default. Making some research I found that it could be also a problem of the server, that is the reason why I mention that I use a Raspberry Pi with Raspian installed as a server. I am using Apache

**Things I have tried already:**

I have tried the solutions shown here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-fix-permalink-postname-404-not-found, and here: [Permalinks in Wordpress - Page not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410921/permalinks-in-wordpress-page-not-found). and in others sites

- I tried the One that says ***Update the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`***, but I don't have that file
- ***Go to /etc/httpd/conf and edit httpd.conf*** but I don't have that file either in my server
- ***Make sure your server is able to write to the .htaccess file.*** Yes, I have already make sure of that, and still nothing
- ***Alter your .htaccess file to add the following to the top of the file:
  `Options +FollowSymlinks`***. I did that, and it didn't work
- ***Enable rewrite_mod by typing (you need to be root) `a2enmod rewrite`***. It is enabled, but still have the error
- ***Restart apache by `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`***. I even reboot my server and nothing

Please, I would appreciate any ideas, Thanks in advance

**Updates:**

- I forgot to say that when I use the personalized structure: `/index.php/%postname%/` it works, but that structure would be a little strange in my website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fix it, here is the solution:

First choose the structure of the permalink that you wish. Then in your raspberrry pi server:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and change this:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

for this:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

restart the apache2 server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And it should be working

Comment: It worked for me even without changing the AllowOverride for directory / (the first one)